# Setting build parameters from external file in TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity

I am currently setting the assembly version on all my C# assemblies using the TeamCity AssemblyInfo Patcher. The version scheme I chose is 'Major.Minor.%build.number%.0'. This works fine when I define Major and Minor numbers in TeamCity, but ideally I would like to have them already defined in my AssemblyInfo.cs file and have TeamCity only set the value for the build number. Is this possible?

One solution I see is to forsake using AssemblyInfo Patcher and use my own version update script, but that seems heavy-handed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a [parameters file](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Project+and+Agent+Level+Build+Parameters#ProjectandAgentLevelBuildParameters-TCdefaultProperties) which you check into version control, and then update the scheme to `%system.major_version%.%system.minor_version%.%build_number%.0`. Then you can keep using AssemblyInfo Patcher, but patch everything based on the values in the props file.

Just put the following in a file named `teamcity.default.properties` in your project root:

```
 system.major_version=3
 system.minor_version=15
```

This will result in the build number `3.15.1234.0` for build #1234.

Comment: I could not get this to work. TeamCity complains that I have no compatible Agent to run my build, because major_version and minor_version are undefined. I even tried pre-defining the parameters, then forcing a sync with my GitHub root, but to no avail. Do I have to create an agent that is tailored to that particular vcs root?

Comment: Is your file called `teamcity.default.properties`?

Comment: I got it to work! By defining my parameters as system parameters (prefix the parameter names with 'system' everywhere they are referenced). I was previously not doing that, and TeamCity was requiring Configuration Parameters.

Comment: @BrunoDenuit-Wojcik: Glad you got it working! :) I updated the answer to reflect what (I think) you did to pull it all together - does the current version of the answer reflect your solution? If not, please do file an edit to the answer that fixes it up, so future viewers get something that works on the first try :)

Comment: @TomasLycken I made one additional edit (adding 'system' to the param declarations in the file too).

Comment: Hi, I found that when following this answer teamcity could not allocate a build agent until I had explicitly added the parameters to the build configuration. Did you have to do this?

Once I'd done that, the assembly info patcher just used the blank default value rather than picking it up from the 'teamcity.default.properties' file. Annoyingly the correct value showed up in the 'parameters' section of the build log, suggesting I have it almost right.

Teamcity v9.1.5 by the way, any advice much appreciated.

Comment: As OlduwanSteve noted, adding the system parameters satisfies the agent but doesn't seem to read my properties file.  This reference on the JetBrains site ( https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Project+and+Agent+Level+Build+Parameters ) indicates setting a checkout rule to ensure that the file is included in the build working directory, but I'm not able to find an example of what the rule should be.  I currently have no checkout rules and am not specifying a specific build working directory, so I expect that the file in the root of my solution should appear in the correct place.

Comment: Has anyone got this to work yet? I've created the `teamcity.default.properties` file, and this file is available in the source code root. However the 'release_number' variable, defined as `release_number=3.3.0` in the file is not read in. Like others, I've had to manually create the parameter in the build definition otherwise it becomes not compatible with the agent, however this value is never replaced with the value in the `teamcity.default.properties` file.